# run Matlab scripts one after the other from a c++ program

Tags: c++, matlab, shell

I have 2 matlab files that execute some commands, and these are called by a c++ program by calling the matlab command-line shell (matlab -r "run .."). I realized there is some delay in between different calls to the shell, since it needs to boot up and exit for the next command, boot up and exit again and so on. Is there a way I can call these files more efficiently, i.e. have one session of the matlab shell running and listening for the function calls, callable from a c++ program?

Comment: Why not just pass the names of both scripts via the `-r` flag? `matlab -r "script1; script2; exit;"`

Comment: @Suever they are called dynamically throughout the program, so above won't work :(

Comment: On which Os is this performed, because if its windows, maybe getting the command console via win-api and injecting the required code into the console?

Comment: @Alex I tried running it your way and it seems to work! thanks!